# How to get all token balances of an address on Ethereum

Tags: erc-20, tokens

So I wanted to retrieve every token balance of one of my adress.
I started by analysing all my transactions.

But then I discovered that I could not trust the transactions's transfer events and that I had to use balanceOf() on each token.

For example those 'RFI' shitcoins that redistribute 15-30% of each swap to every holder do it by internally adapting the balance of each holder, there is no transfert happening so if you just add up every transfert in the end you don't get the real balance.

But more than that : a token contract could be deployed with an amount allocated to my public adress.

**Does this mean that the only way to really know is to parse EVERY BLOCKs for EVERY TOKENs creation and then later query balanceOf() on EVERY TOKENs?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that the only way to really know is to parse EVERY BLOCKs for EVERY TOKENs creation and then later query balanceOf() on EVERY TOKENs?

You are correct. There is no API or any trick to get ERC-20 balances in reliable manner, or the list tokens an address holds.

[Ethereum is 2014 era tech and not very helpful for building any kind of applications](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1656215016016683008).

Also `balanceOf()` is a function that can lie, so there is no way at all to know the balance of an arbitrary token, especially if it is malicious or a scam.